# Facebook Style New Post Notification

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, notifications

Does anybody know how I can use the following tutorial, which provides near realtime notifications when a user comments, and hook it into the wordpress publish_post hook?

Here is my current function which sends users an email when a new post is published:

```
add_action('publish_listings', 'vba_update', 10, 1);
add_action('draft_listings', 'vba_update', 10, 1);
function vba_update($post_id){ 
$args = array(
'include'   => tb_get_followers($user_id)
);
$user_query = new WP_User_Query($args);

if ( !empty($user_query->results) ) : 

$post_title = get_the_title( $post_id ); 
$post_url = get_permalink( $post_id ); 
$subject = 'A post has been updated'; 
$message = "A post has been updated on your website:\n\n";
$message .= "<a href='". $post_url. "'>" .$post_title. "</a>\n\n"; 

/** Send an individual message to each user */
foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) :
    wp_mail($user->data->user_email, $subject, $message);
endforeach;
endif; 
}
```

and here is the link to the tutorial I am referring to: https://www.webslesson.info/2017/02/facebook-style-notifications-in-php.html

Any help would be greatly appreciated!